# Progress View and background loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

my code is loading 7 pics from url and adding their data to an array. in the end of the process I do get an 8 objects array, but I'm trying to show a progress bar until the process of loading all the photos finished.

I do not have an idea how to do that...

here is the code

```
-(void)SetUpDrinks
{
    loadingView.hidden=NO;
    [loadingView_activity startAnimating];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=YES;
        imgsDATA = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
            imageDownloadNum++;
            absPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://domain/app/menu/drinks/%i.png",imageDownloadNum];
            trimmedAbsPath = [absPath stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
            NSURL *imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:trimmedAbsPath];
            NSLog(@"%@",imgURL);
            imgDATA = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:imgURL];
            [imgsDATA addObject:imgDATA];
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            loadingView.hidden=YES;
            [loadingView_activity stopAnimating];
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;
            [self RefreshImg];
        });

    });

}
```

Comment: Check out MBProgressHud here https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Comment: How about using a progress component? There is plenty of them if you seach in cocoacontrols.

Comment: Will try the "MBProgressHud" looks good.

Comment: Im trying to use the determinate mode and it is not working.
It show the hud but the progress bar is not filling

Answer (score 0):

You could make an [NSOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) subclass to download your image and then use a dispatch_group. Dispatch groups are a way to block a thread until one or more tasks finish executing - in this scenario we are waiting for all of your downloads to finish.

You can now use the `progressBlock` to update the UI and let the user know how many of the images have finished downloading.

If you want progress for an individual download then take a look at the [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) reference. In particular `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data`

```
- (void)enqueueGroupOfOperations:(NSArray *)operations
                        progress:(void (^)(NSUInteger completedCount, NSUInteger totalOperations))progressBlock
                      completion:(void (^)(NSArray *operations))completionBlock;
{

  NSParameterAssert(operations);
  NSParameterAssert(progress);
  NSParameterAssert(completion);

  __block dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
  NSBlockOperation *dependentOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
      dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          completion(operations);
      });
      dispatch_release(group);
  }];

  for (NSOperation *operation in operations) {

      operation.completionBlock = ^{
          dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

              NSUInteger count = [[operations indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSOperation *operation, NSUInteger idx,  BOOL *stop) {
                  return [operation isFinished];
              }] count];

              progress(count, [operations count]);

              dispatch_group_leave(group);
          });
      };

      dispatch_group_enter(group);
      [dependentOperation addDependency:operation];
  }

  [self.operationQueue addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:NO];
  [self.operationQueue addOperation:dependentOperation];
}
```

If this is too much for you then you can go over to `AFNetworking` where this is all done for you, https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking. But its always nice to know how some of this stuff works.